# <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selection". works with Mouse but with touch pad it works only on finger touches on a certain angle

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Angular from VS Code but my current project, which is a maintainence project, has all the UI in Angular (VS Code).

In this code I have a

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selection" (change)="changeMode()" name="select" id="option-real ...
```

I works fine, shows a drop down and the desired options in the drop down which are mutually exclusive.

However, when I try to pull the drop down using the touch pad on the laptop, the drop down is pulled correctly but the selection of the items in the drop down happen only when the touch pad is touched at certain points with the finger in a certain angle.

This is happening across laptops - touch pads.

When using a mouse this works correctly though.

Can this be rectified? Please advice.

Comment: Angular does not have control over your touch drivers, so angles and touch points on a hardware level are not directly accessible by Angular Components whatsoever. I strongly recommend to retest on a variety of touch devices, such as tablets - first of all to reproduce the issue. Please post your findings here.

Comment: I have checked this. It works correctly for a mouse click or a touch screen, stylus enabled devices. The issue is with the laptop touch pad.